# implicit property validation with class-validator library

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I need to validate a string property. I add the `@IsString()` decorator and I set the property type `string` as well.

```
import { IsString, IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";

export class SomeDto {
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    public readonly someField: string;
}
```

It is quite a duplication. Is it possible to have the type validation implicit without the `IsString()` decorator, since it's defined as a type hint already?

```
import { IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";

export class SomeDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    public readonly someField: string;
}
```

Comment: seems that @IsNotEmpty() Checks if given value is not empty (!== '', !== null, !== undefined). so you can use just @IsNotEmpty

Comment: it will pass the validation if the numeric value is provided